# How to send a file from .net via post web api

Tags: c#, file, post

I have a method that recive a file  vía post, I want to take this file from the request and send it to a REST request(also POST)

This is what i got:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFisle(string exp, string req)
    {
        var user = GetAuthenticatedUser();
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RestReclam"] + "/PendingFiles/" + user.Dni + "/" + exp + "/" + req + "/token";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
        var resp = client.PostAsync(url, provider.Contents[0]).Result;
        return resp;
    }
```

Comment: And what happened? Do you have an error?

Comment: yes, I'm getting a 415  error, apparently the media type is wrong, but I cant change it and   don't know if this is the correct way to send a file.

Comment: HttpClient is not a Net Library method.  It looks like it is a custom class that inherits the HttpRequest.  There is an error in the HttpClient code that you didn't post.  I would start by using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to find root cause of issue and fix the client.  The Net library error messages are not as good and the data that you will get with a sniffer.